# Using XML as a SQL Parameter to load multiple objects

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, .net-3.5

I'm a newbie at this, so bear with me for a second.

I have a dictionary like so:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, SalesStatistics>();
```

SalesStatistics is a custom class; that contains various information about products.  The key field holds the ProductId.

I need to iterate across this dictionary, and for each ProductId in the dictionary; I need to load a Product class.  Since this dictionary contains about 20,000 records; I don't want to ding my database every time I need a Product object.  Ideally; I'd like to pass in the XML list of Id's, load all of them into a ProductsCollection, and then pull the Products object from my loaded collection.  This should allow me to hit the database once.

Anybody have some tips/tricks to get me going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the Id's as a comma separated varchar and break them up using [fn_Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496058(SQL.80).aspx)

Or use [SQL XML](http://daveclarkesblog.blogspot.com/2007/09/passing-lists-to-sql-server-stored.html) to break it put into a table and Join it - I don't have a better example at home, sorry.

Comment: Well, XML is definitely the preferred way to do this IMO; and I found that this link is more detailed:  http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx